# href won't go to upper div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a function for smooth scrolling and it's working fine, as long as the `div` is beneath the point where I currently am on the page.

If I click another `href` that is above it won't go. Instead, it would just go down and down.

This is my code:

```js
$(".test").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.getAttribute("href")).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<a href="#2">Go to 2</a>
<div id="1"> content </div>
<a href="#1">Go to 1</a>
<div id="2"> content </div><br>
```

Note that it won't work even if I don't use the js, when clicking it would just go below.`<br>`

Something like this, think that by clicking on "Go to 1" it won't work

Comment: _"Note that it won't work even if i don't use the js"_ - Then why do you think it is relevant for this question? Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you have hooked up your HTML but your sample code does not show the `test` class anywhere.

Using your code, adding the `test` class to the links and giving the divs some height using CSS to ensure scrolling will occur works right out of the box.

There is a slight flicker though as the animation is executing at the same time as the default "go-To" functionality, to stop that use `preventDefault()` to ensure only your animation is moving the page.

The below seems to work.

```js
$(".test").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.getAttribute("href")).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test" href="#2">Go to 2</a>
<div id="1"> content of 1</div>
<a class="test" href="#1">Go to 1</a>
<div id="2">content of 2</div>
```